# contextmenu does not work in desktop

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I am using ubuntu12.04, and I install the gnome-classic desktop.

After that I removed the package 'nautilus', and install the 'thunar'.

However, I found that the context menu does not work anymore.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome Nautilus is used to manage the desktop background including showing the icons and the context menu.

Thunar can not do this so you need to either install Nautilus or another program to manage the desktop background, for example `xfdesktop4`.

If you use a program other than Nautilus you may need to add it to your autostart programs to start it at login time.